# How to run http put request in a loop and get status of every individual request

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, angular-services

I have an array of object and each of its objects needs to be updated in database through a put http request.

```js
[
{id: "3e81731f-e3b4-405d-a5ca-bef52c1b036a", date_created: "2019-07-24T15:55:31.372460Z", date_modified: "2020-07-13T03:25:02.720870Z", einsight_uuid: "d15176ab-ecf8-dba1-e040-10ac316407fa", attributes: {…}},
{id: "4707bff2-8265-456f-a4d4-ca1134d85620", date_created: "2019-07-24T15:55:31.372460Z", date_modified: "2020-07-13T03:25:06.238019Z", einsight_uuid: "fcda4259-3ecb-4566-85b0-5b6d5c7647f6", attributes: {…}}
{id: "d29a3340-04b6-431b-8671-a0f0d25a9b51", date_created: "2019-07-24T15:55:31.3724", date_modified: "2020-07-13T03:25:06.238019Z", einsight_uuid: "fcda4259-3ecb-4566-85b0-5b6d5c7647f6", attributes: {…}}
]
```

how can i call the api to save each record in array. Calling Api in a loop is an easy option but its not sufficient. i want to keep record of each response. how many of them succeeded or failed .
Is there any available known best practice to perform such kind of action in angular or rxjs

Comment: Every time you call your api you will get a `observable` response, to which you can `.subscribe()`. Inside of those `subscribe` callbacks you will have the response for each and every request. Does this fit your requirement?

Comment: Yea i can do it this way. i can subscribe the response and update user with every records status. So its totally fine to call a put request in loop? There is no performance issue? I was wondering if there is something available for put like we have ForkJoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it either in parallel or sequential requests based on the number of requests and your requirement.

#### Parallel requests

Use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) function with [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) and [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operators. Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

putDataParallel() {
  let success = 0;                   // <-- trivial counters
  let errors = 0;

  const reqs = this.urls.map(url =>  // <-- replate `this.urls` with your object array
    this.http.put(url).pipe(         // <-- replace `url` with your own PUT request
      tap(_ => success++),           // <-- count successful responses here
      catchError(err => {        
        errors++;                    // <-- count errors here
        return of(err);              // <-- remember to return an observable from `catchError`
      })
    )
  );

  forkJoin(reqs).subscribe(
    null,                            // <-- you could change response callback to your requirement
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log(`Success: ${success}\nErrors: ${errors}`),
  );
}
```

#### Sequential requests

Use RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) function and [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) operator for sequential stream of data. Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

putDataSequential() {
  let success = 0;                      // <-- trivial counters
  let errors = 0;

  from(this.urls).pipe(                 // <-- replate `this.urls` with your object array
    concatMap(url => {
      return this.http.put(url).pipe(   // <-- replace `url` with your own PUT request
        tap(_ => success++),            // <-- count successful responses here
        catchError(err => {        
          errors++;                     // <-- count errors here
          return of(err);               // <-- remember to return an observable from `catchError`
        })
      )
    })
  ).subscribe(
    null,                               // <-- you could change response callback to your requirement
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log(`Success: ${success}\nErrors: ${errors}`),
  );
}
```

Both the methods will run until all the objects in the array are completed regardless of errors or responses. If you however wish to break the sequence in case of an error, replace the `return of(err);` statement in the `catchError` operator to throw an `error` or `complete` notification instead. For example you could use RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant: `return EMPTY;`.

I've used trivial counters as an example. You could instead use objects (for eg.) to log both the number of response/errors and corresponding input to the HTTP request.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u7mymy)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rxjs concat but concat will stop in case observable throw an error so you can use catchError to return a new observable

```js
import { of ,concat} from 'rxjs';
....
 data = [
    {id:1},
    {id:2},
    {id:-1},
    {id:2},

    ]
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){
    let httpReqs = this.data
          .map(i => 
              this.http.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${i.id}`,{})
              .pipe(catchError(err => of({err})))
              );

     concat(...httpReqs).subscribe(console.log)
    }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ddjzt)

check this  [rxjs concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i dont want to stop it till it finishes for all records.

Comment: concat  will stop in case an error but I use catchError to return a new observable in that case the next observable will run ,check the demo console

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, each item will be processed with **concateMap** and after making an `HTTP` request, each item `result`array will be updated.
There are multiple ways, you can achieve this result. This is one of the ways shown here.

```
 items =[
       {id: "3e81731f-e3b4-405d-a5ca-bef52c1b036a", name :'united', result:[]},
       {id: "4707bff2-8265-456f-a4d4-ca1134d85620", name: 'ind', result:[]},
       {id: "d29a3340-04b6-431b-8671-a0f0d25a9b51", name:'ru', result:[]},
       {id: "xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx", name:'', result:[]}
    ]



from(this.items)
    .pipe(
        concatMap(item => this.ob2(item.name).pipe(
          catchError(err=>of(err)),
          tap(result =>{
            if(result.length){
              item.result = result;
            }else{
              // error scenario can be handled here
            }
            console.log('Updated each item', item)
          })
        ))
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nyks-update-array-after-making-http-request?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**